# Pandas join 2 dataframes

Tags: python, join, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

```
>>> result
         id   order_nr
0   3131334  334756912
0   3131312  386517432
0   3131309  356299432
0   3131205  397514312
          ...

>>> OMSdf
     order_nr            status  refund_amount
0   377766482  already_canceled              0
1   348722582  already_canceled              0
2   395287472           on_hold              0
3   345883652  already_canceled              0
          ...
```

Those 2 dataframes have some common values in the field "order_nr":

```
>>> result[result['order_nr'] == '377766482']
        id   order_nr
0  3129153  377766482

>>> OMSdf[OMSdf['order_nr'] == '377766482']
    order_nr            status  refund_amount
0  377766482  already_canceled              0
```

But I try to join them together:

```
resultfinal = result.join(OMSdf, on='order_nr', how='inner', lsuffix='', rsuffix='_oms', sort=False)
```

the result is empty:

```
>>> resultfinal
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, order_nr, order_nr_oms, status, refund_amount]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code

```
df_merged = pd.merge(result, OMSdf, how='inner')
```

In your case, you can make `order_nr` as the index for both the dataframes before joining, as follows

```
result.index = result['order_nr']
OMSdf.index = OMSdf['order_nr']
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I don't understand why the first syntax doesn't

Comment: Please look at the edited response. Basically you need to convert the index before joining